# couchdb gen_server call timeout during purge

Tags: java, erlang, timeout, couchdb, purge

I'm running an analysis on time duration to run a couchdb purge using a java program. The couchdb connections and calls are handled using ektorp. For a small number of documents purging takes place and I receive a success response.

But when I purge ~ 10000 or more, I get the following error:

```
    org.ektorp.DbAccessException: 500:Internal Server Error
    URI: /dbname/_purge
    Response Body: 
    {
      "error" : "timeout",
      "reason" : "{gen_server,call,
....
```

On checking the db status using a curl command, the actual purging has taken place. But this timeout does not allow me to monitor the actual time of the purging method in my java program since this throws an exception.

On some research, I believe this is due to a default timeout value of an erlang gen_server process. Is there anyway for me to fix this?

I have tried changing the timeout values of the StdHttpClient to no avail.

```
HttpClient authenticatedHttpClient = new StdHttpClient.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .username(Conf.COUCH_USERNAME)
                    .password(Conf.COUCH_PASSWORD)
                    .connectionTimeout(600*1000)
                    .socketTimeout(600*1000)
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

CouchDB Dev here. You are not supposed to use purge with large numbers of documents. This is to remove accidentally added data from the DB, like credit card or social security numbers. This isn’t meant for general operations.

Consequently, you can’t raise that `gen_server` timeout :)

Comment: thank you for the response, its basically a case of deleted data collected over a period of time. hence looking at a one-time purging option to free up disk space. 
A related question: Is there any possibility of data corruption through purging  of a large number of deleted docs?

Comment: for time-series data, we’d recommend a database per $interval, so you can simply delete previous’ interval’s databases. 

Data corruption: no, everything in CouchDB is append_only and fsync()’d safely.